# Protect GET Request from Android App over API

Tags: php, android, api

I want to get JSON Array over an API. The API we created works well, but we are worried as we are using the API over our Android App and it might be easier to de-compile the APK and get access to our API. As it is an Android Application, we are unable to restrict access by IP.

However, we would like to protect access to that API PHP File accept the one via the App. Is there any way to authenticate the pull request made by the App at server's end.

**Note: We are using Amazon EC2 Instance. I won't post the direct access to the file or our server here.**

Comment: Can you provide us some code, so we can help you?

Comment: there is no way to protect rest api. use proguard or some commercial solution for protect dex from decompile.

Comment: If someone can perfectly reverse-engineer your APK then any sort of security implemented within that APK is not really safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the APK's signing signature like this using the PackageManager class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

```
Signature[] sigs = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
for (Signature sig : sigs) {
    Log.i("MyApp", "Signature hashcode : " + sig.hashCode());
}
```

We can use this to compare with the hashcode for our debug key, or release key,  to identify whether the APK is a debug APK or a release APK, or signed with any other signature.

So if anyone try to obfuscate your apk, signature of app will change.

> You have to make changes to the API and you need to send the signature
>   of app in the Restful API so that server can be sure that the API call
>   is genuine.

Also you need to enable proguard in the app while building it so that it makes obfuscation hard.

Hope that helps.
Cheers!!

Comment: Excellent comments. *Nevertheless,* be sure that you do not try to implement "security through obscurity" either in your API or in your client-side implementation of it. The client-side is never "trustworthy." You must carefully design your API, and must "harden" the host-side implementation of it, on the presumption that somehow the client that you are talking to, either "has been thoroughly compromised," or "is *altogether* 'a rogue.'"